# column indices (start + span) mustn't exceed the column count

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to copy the red do to all the rest of squares but when I try and do that I get the error "column indices (start + span) mustn't exceed the column count"

[image]

I set the column and the row count to 3. my XML code is a below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.zubai.connect3.MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:src="@drawable/red"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:src="@drawable/red"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:src="@drawable/red"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />


    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have set grid view row and column count to 3 both when I was copying the red dot to the next cell instead of choosing the cell next to it which appears in green grid lines I was pasting it in cells further away from the cell. It only works when you copy the dot to the grid next to it sticking to the number. I could also do this in the XML view by making sure I stuck to the numbers specified.